# Output values inside class object

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I want to output values inside the class object to the console. Here's my code. This won't work. There is no error, but this won't output the values. 
    This is my method.

```
public ClsPayeDetails get_paydetail_byrow(int rowno)
{

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM s07_01_payeDetails WHERE row_no='"+rowno+"'";
    DataRow dr = LogIn.HR_Connection.GetSingleRow(sql);
    ClsPayeDetails obj_det = null;
    if (dr != null)
        {
            obj_det = new ClsPayeDetails(
                decimal.Parse(dr["reducing_value"].ToString()),
                dr["financial_year"].ToString(),
                decimal.Parse(dr["lower_limit"].ToString()),
                decimal.Parse(dr["upper_limit"].ToString()),
                decimal.Parse(dr["percentage"].ToString())
                );
        }

        Console.WriteLine(obj_det.ToString());
        return obj_det;
 }        
// and this is where i call it. I think i'm doing this in incorrect way. //Any help would be appreciated.

 private void testDetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cc_payroll.pyrl_cls_master.ClsPayeDetails dd = new cc_payroll.pyrl_cls_master.ClsPayeDetails();
            dd.get_paydetail_byrow(1);                  
        }
```

Comment: "this won't output the values" - what does this mean? output where? to Console in a Windows Forms application?

Comment: Where's your ToString() method implementation?

Comment: ToString() method implementation? sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: I did the mistake. I wanted to output values to console in a windows forms application. and the console.writeline() should not be put here. it should put in where I call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
Console.WriteLine(obj_det.ToString());
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(obj_det.getXXXXXXX().ToString());
```

getXXXXXXX() is your attribute in the class ClsPayeDetails.

Comment: tried. but then it requires an argument. but i'm passing it already through the main form. what can I do for it?

Comment: That was the code of it. I don't get what part you asking.

Comment: obj_det is a ClsPayeDetails object, you can not print the object directly.

You have pass the data to the constructor. obj_det = new ClsPayeDetails(x, x, x, x, x ); so that, there are some fields (getter, setter) in the ClsPayeDetails;

You can mouse over on the ClsPayeDetails and press F12 to see the object in visual studio.

Comment: in here i created class object to call that method. but this is inside the main form.                                                                                            cc_payroll.pyrl_cls_master.ClsPayeDetails dd = new cc_payroll.pyrl_cls_master.ClsPayeDetails();
dd.get_paydetail_byrow(1);

Answer (score 1):

ToString() function designed to return the value of 'single value object' like int, string... etc else it returns the object type.

So you need to:

1. Overwrite the function Tostring() in your class'ClsPayeDetails' to return a value not the type
2. Get object's properties and its values automatically.

   you can use this code as it's or return any other string you want.

   ```
   public override string ToString()
   {
       string result = "";
       foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) result += Environment.NewLine;
           result += p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(this);
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `override string ToString` function in your ClsPayeDetails class

```
public class ClsPayeDetails
{
    //Your property class

    public override string ToString()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder val = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        val.Append(string.Format("reducing_value = {0},", reducing_value));
        val.Append(string.Format("financial_year = {0},", financial_year));
        val.Append(string.Format("lower_limit = {0},", lower_limit));
        val.Append(string.Format("upper_limit = {0},", upper_limit));
        val.Append(string.Format("percentage = {0},", percentage));
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. I changed my method go static and then accessed by class.

```
  private void testDetToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cc_payroll.pyrl_cls_master.ClsPayeDetails dd = ClsPayeDetails.get_paydetail_byrow(2);
            Console.WriteLine(dd.FinancialYear.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dd.lowerLimit.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dd.upperLimit.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dd.percenTage.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dd.adjust.ToString());

        }
```

and the method is

```
  public static ClsPayeDetails get_paydetail_byrow(int rowno)
        {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM s07_01_payeDetails WHERE row_no='" + rowno + "'";
                DataRow dr = LogIn.HR_Connection.GetSingleRow(sql);
                ClsPayeDetails obj_det = null;
                if (dr != null)
                {
                    obj_det = new ClsPayeDetails(
                        decimal.Parse(dr["reducing_value"].ToString()),
                        dr["financial_year"].ToString(),
                        decimal.Parse(dr["lower_limit"].ToString()),
                        decimal.Parse(dr["upper_limit"].ToString()),
                        decimal.Parse(dr["percentage"].ToString())
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This row does not exist !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            return obj_det;
        }
```